# Getting the_content from one page and displaying it in another (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I looking for a way to get the_content from one of my pages and display it in another page. Preferably by using the page slug/title.

I found a code that seems to work but it uses the page id. Is there a way to modify this code so that it uses the page slug/title?

```
<div>
   <?php
      $id = 238;
      $p = get_page($id);
      echo apply_filters('the_content', $p->post_content);
   ?>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: by name do you mean the page slug or title? check [get_page_by_title](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) out

Comment: It could be either the slug or the title @d79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By title:

```
<div>
    <?php
        $page = get_page_by_title( 'Page Title' );
        if( $page ) {
            echo apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content);
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

By slug:

```
<div>
    <?php
        $page = get_page_by_path( 'page-title' );
        if($page) {
            echo apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content);
        }
    ?>
</div>
```